# How to use jQuery atuto complete textboxes with DataTables

Tags: php, mysql, autocomplete, datatables, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI DataTables, which is working smoothly.

I have about 20 odd filteration options. Some are dropdowns, some date picker and quite a few textboxes. I want to make these textboxes to auto complete with the data from database.

On and off I have been banging my head with it for a week now.

Is it possitble to have auto complete with teh DataTables if yes HOW?

Any suggestion wil be a life saver.

[image]

Comment: U having html table which contains drop downs, date picker, text box and u implemented datatable in this html. Now u want text box with auto complete.Am i right?

Comment: No its the other way around. 

I am using DataTables and it works great. 

Few of the filtration options is a textbox … where when user types something it filters the table.

Now I want to make these textboxes as autocompete. Means when the user starts typing in a textbox after two characters it should start giving related words options from the database.

Comment: That means u want auto complete in datatable filter?

Comment: Give some example how u want..

Comment: I have added the screen grab of what I want to do. I hope it makes more sense.

Comment: there is nothing to do with datatable. just use auto complete in that text box.

Comment: Use `minlength: 2` in auto complete. so it will display only when user typed 2 words.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. U r using php so it would be like this.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var LocalityArray = [];
  //$.getJSON('../../database/country.json', { id: data.id }, function(response) {
    $.getJSON("locality.php", { getLocality: '495074' }, function(response) {
        // Here (response) is array format. Like this

        // [{"LocalityID":9397,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Adugodi"},{"LocalityID":9398,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Aga Abbas Ali Road"},{"LocalityID":9399,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Agaram"},{"LocalityID":9400,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Agrahara Dasara Halli"},{"LocalityID":9401,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Agrahara Dasarahalli"},{"LocalityID":9402,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Airport Exit Road"},{"LocalityID":9403,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Horamavu"},{"LocalityID":9404,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Hosakere Halli"},{"LocalityID":9405,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Hennur"},{"LocalityID":9406,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Hesaraghatta"},{"LocalityID":9407,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"HKP Road"},{"LocalityID":9408,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"HMT Layout"},{"LocalityID":9409,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Hongasandra"},{"LocalityID":9410,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Hoody"},{"LocalityID":9411,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Hayes Road"}    ]

        $.each(response, function(key, value) {
            LocalityArray[key] = value.LocalityName;
        });

        $(".txtLocality").autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: LocalityArray
        });
    }, 'json');

});
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="txtLocality" />
            <input type="text" class="txtLocality" />
            <input type="text" class="txtLocality" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the auto complete working using the DataTable codes itself.

Instead I used a jQuery plug-in called [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). It has served the purpose well. It is very simple and easy to use.

I hope it can be helpful for someone else.